# Is it likely that Abraham Lincoln knew about the Pyramids at Giza?

Tags: slavery, american-civil-war, racism

Lincoln's complicated views on race are well documented. That he believed the black man to be inferior to the white man in every way is beyond dispute, at least in his earlier years. Obviously, he was a product of his time, and his views simply reflect the most common and pervasive attitudes of the day. But I also have to wonder how much of these attitudes were a product of mere ignorance and parochialism. Clearly, Lincoln was trained as a lawyer, and despite his rural upbringing, must have learned much more than the average American of his time. Surely he would have learned about the Seven Wonders of the World at some point? That Africans built the largest megastructures in history, unrivalled even in his day? Or is it plausible that he had no such knowledge of Egyptian culture, despite having a law degree?

Comment: Lincoln must have been aware of the reverse side of the Great Seal of the United States.

Comment: Why do you assume that there is any equivalence between African people and black people?

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: @MAGolding I wasn't aware that there was a meaningful number of American slaves at the time of Lincoln that weren't African. Or perhaps you mean that light-skinned Africans, such as some north Africans are not considered "black"?

Comment: @LawnmowerMan, I seriously doubt that Lincoln would have equated the ancient Egyptians with the slaves in the Southern states. They would have been interpreted as part of the Middle Eastern culture and population.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Richard J. Oglesby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_J._Oglesby), the man that attached the '[rail-splitter' phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_J._Oglesby#:%7E:text=it%20may%20have%20been%20he%20who%20applied%20the%20moniker%20%22Railsplitter%22%20to%20Lincoln.) to Lincoln,   did an extended tour of Europe and the 'Holy Land' in 1857. He did many talks on what he had observed on his return. Page 29 of the book [**Lincoln's Rail-splitter**](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Lincoln_s_Rail_splitter/9nwph67cSqAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=lincoln%20talk%20egypt%20pyramids&pg=PA29&printsec=frontcover), by Mark A Plummer, mentions that Lincoln had listened  to one of these presentations:

> Lincoln heard Oglesby's Holy Land speech in Bloomington and remarked
> to Judge David Davis, "*Here we have a young man who has been at the
> Pyramids, and stood on the ground where the Messiah and Abraham stood,
> and this seems to bring the human family a little closer together.*" It
> was a favorable comment that presaged Oglesby's political involvement
> with the Rail-Splitter.

So yes, we have historical evidence that Lincoln was aware of the Pyramids.

Comment: Wow, fantastic find. I don't know how one would even find a reference like this without knowing something about it beforehand. It certainly didn't appear in any searches I did.